Missing required argument when a required parameter is declared inside a dynamic block
I am looking for a solution to the error Missing required argument when a required argument is declared in a dynamic block.
In the below example,  resource_two has the arguments version & id  that are required. With this config, I always get an error stating Missing required argument.
resource "resource_one" "sample" {
  for_each = { for sl in var.sample_list : sl.name => sl }
  name     = each.value.name
}

resource "resource_two" "sample" {
  for_each = { for sl in var.sample_list : sl.name => sl }

  dynamic "v" {
    for_each = each.value.versions
    content {
      version = v.value.version
      id      = resource_one[each.key].id
    }
  }
}

variable "sample_list" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    versions = list(object({
      id      = string
      version = number
    }))
  }))
}

I tried with try function in terraform but that didn't work.
is this possible to add required variable in a dynamic block?

It seems that resource_two depends on resource_one, to fix your issue you can use depends_on like this:
`resource "resource_two" "sample" {
for_each = { for sl in var.sample_list : sl.name => sl }
depends_on = [resource_one]
...
}`

Depending on the Terraform version you're using, you could set the version attribute as optional, see: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#optional-object-type-attributes.
